# Change time format to be able to get correct average

Tags: excel, excel-formula, time, average

I am trying to calculate the average time taken to complete a training program by the users. The report in Excel gives the times as 01h 13m 31s.  I have 199 of these formatted times in a column. Some of them have 00h 42m 19s. I think I need to change them all to a format of 01:13:31 to average them. Or do I? I'm trying to do this in excel. I'm not a coder. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I do this with a combination of find(), mid() and iferror() -  pulling out the relevant numbers and converting to decimal so the calcs work, oftem I just work in seconds, so number of hours * 3600 etc

Comment: It depends on what is stored vs what is displayed.  When you click on the cell do you see the value in the formula bar as a time like `01:13:31 AM` or do you see the string `01h 13m 31s`?

Comment: @ScottCraner I assumed that it would be the string.

Comment: If it is a string then in another cell: `=--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"h ",":"),"m ",":"),"s","")` then format it `[hh]:mm:ss` and you can do your math on it.  If not a string then just use you math on the cells.

Comment: @SolarMike why assume, it could easily be a time with a cell format of `hh\h mm\m ss\s` you are most likely correct, but I like to make sure.

Comment: Fred You could also do this if those text time are in actually like this `00h 00m 00s` then using the formula which is accessible in `MS365` `=SUM(TEXTSPLIT(A2,{"h","m","s"},,1)*{3600,60,1})/86400` assuming you have a header in first row and data starts from row 2 onwards and later format the cells as `[hh]:mm:ss`

Comment: Even more better would be `=TEXTJOIN(":",1,TEXTSPLIT(A2,{"h","m","s"},,1))+0`, however before going to further deep, first select the cells and hit `CTRL+SHIFT+~` if those turns into decimals then they are custom formatted as already mentioned above by @ScottCraner Sir, (could be), if not then use a formula

Comment: I see the string 00h 42m 14s in the formula bar.

Comment: Then you now have three formula in the comments that will do the conversion.

Comment: I just used this formula   =SUM(TEXTSPLIT(T2:T200,{"h","m","s"},,1)*   but it gives an error that it is missing an opening or closing parenthesis. I tried adding one in front and in back but got other errors from that

Comment: Hi Fred sir, it is correct since it is self explanatory, from your comments you are certainly missing something at the end and that is you need to enter `{3600,60,1})/86400` after the multiplication symbol. See I have posted in `Answers` for more clarity.

Comment: I just tried using this formula   =TEXTJOIN(":",1,TEXTSPLIT(T2:T200,{"h","m","s"},,1))+0   and got an error #NAME?

Comment: That means the provided function doesnt supports your version of excel. You need to use either `FILTERXML()` or as mentioned by @ScottCraner Sir. What is your excel version please

Comment: I just added the extra section like this  =SUM(TEXTSPLIT(T2:T200,{"h","m","s"},,1)*{3600,60,1})/86400 and I now receive  the #NAME? error again

Comment: Certainly as i have already mentioned in comments and answers, as well, formula is excel dependent. what is your version please

Comment: use `=--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"h ",":"),"m ",":"),"s","")`  since you do not have office 365 Excel.

Comment: Or, this one: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(IFERROR(MID(0&A1,SEARCH({"h","m","s"},0&A1)-2,2),{0,0,0})),{3600,60,1})/86400`

Comment: I was using it in 2019, but just opened it in 365 and still get the name error.

Comment: You are getting error, may be thats because you are using an whole array, where as the formula given is based on single cell, in `MS365` you should not be getting a name error unless you are using other language versions.

Comment: I also just tried closing everything from MS I had open and tried reopening it in 365 and the name error is still there

Comment: Can you edit your post to show a screencap of the error

Comment: I just tried deleting :T200 from the formula and still got the name error msg. I would have thought it would have given me the average of the one cell at least.

Comment: Sorry not `MS365`

Answer (score 1):

Since you have those times stored as text, then assuming there is no excel constraints as per the tags, you could use either of the following with <kbd>TEXTSPLIT( )</kbd> & <kbd>TEXTJOIN( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=TEXTJOIN(":",1,TEXTSPLIT(A1,{"h","m","s"},,1))+0
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C1</kbd>

```
=SUM(TEXTSPLIT(A1,{"h","m","s"},,1)*{3600,60,1})/86400
```

---

Caveat: Ensure to change the format of the cells and ranges you are working with. The custom format you can apply is <kbd>[hh]:mm:ss</kbd> or you could select the cells and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to open format cells under Number Tab --> Category to select Time and select the format shown in screenshot below.

[image]

---

Edit, from the comments above seems OP is not using `MS365` here is an alternative approach:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(IFERROR(MID(0&A1,SEARCH({"h","m","s"},0&A1)-2,2),{0,0,0})),{3600,60,1})/86400
```

---

There are many ways of doing this, perhaps, since in your data you have all in `00h 00m 00s` format hence the above solutions with <kbd>TEXTSPLIT( )</kbd> will work but if sometime, either `h` or `m` or `s` is missing the first two won't work but the 3rd one will work and here is another way, i have tried.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=SUM(IFERROR(MID(0&A1,SEARCH({"h","m","s"},0&A1)-2,2),{0,0,0})*{"1:0:0","0:1:0","0:0:1"})
```

---

Also if you want a single cell formula that will spill, then use this following formula that will even work when either of the time units are missing, see for reference in the screenshot.

[image]

---

```
=MAP(A1:A8,LAMBDA(x,
          SUM(IFERROR(MID(0&x,
          SEARCH({"h","m","s"},0&x)-2,2),{0,0,0})*
          {"1:0:0","0:1:0","0:0:1"})))
```

---

[image]

---

Few more alternatives:

• in cell <kbd>H2</kbd>

```
=REDUCE(A2:A7,{"h ","m ","s"},LAMBDA(x,y,SUBSTITUTE(x,y,":")))+0
```

---

• in cell <kbd>G2</kbd>

```
=DROP(REDUCE("",A2:A7,LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,TEXTJOIN(":",1,TEXTSPLIT(y,{"h","m","s"},,1))+0))),1)
```

---

• in cell <kbd>F2</kbd>

```
=MAP(A2:A7,LAMBDA(x,SUM(IFERROR(
     MID(0&x,SEARCH({"h","m","s"},0&x)-3,3),{0,0,0})
     *{"1:0:0","0:1:0","0:0:1"})))
```

---

Comment: I thank you all for your help. My brain is fried from working on this the last few hours. I'll get back after it tomorrow. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Here is a single cell formula to turn all of your data into proper time. Just change range D4:D23 below to your cell range and update the formatting of the cells to Time.

```
=LET(
    d, D5:D24,
    rm, "hms ",
    t, REDUCE(
        REDUCE(
            d,
            MID(rm, SEQUENCE(LEN(rm)), 1),
            LAMBDA(u, v, SUBSTITUTE(u, v, ""))
        ),
        {3, 6},
        LAMBDA(v, a, REPLACE(v, a, 0, ""))
    ),
    TIME(LEFT(t, 2), MID(t, 3, 2), RIGHT(t, 2))
)
```