# I would like to convert a text string into a standard time format in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of data that has been output like this:

```
Travel Time
1 hour 3 mins
46 mins
52 mins
1 hour 10 mins
```

And I would like it to automatically be converted into an h:mm format like this

```
1:03
0:46
0:52
1:10
```

Not sure what formula to use

I have tried using SUBSTITUTE like this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE([@[Travel Time]]," hour ",":"),"mins","")
```

but this results in

```
1:3 
46 
52 
55 
56 
34 
1:10
```

Comment: In case of more than one hour: is it then "hours"?

Comment: What version do you have?

Comment: it would become "hours", yes.

Comment: Excel 365 2019 is the version

Comment: Have you tried looking into this post: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76925059/8162520) there are some solutions posted

Comment: Try this : `=MAP(A2:A5,LAMBDA(x,SUM(IFERROR(MID(0&x,SEARCH({"h","m"},0&x)-3,3),{0,0})*{"1:0","0:1"})))`

Comment: I have one question, is there any possibility that you will have only an hour and no minutes as well?

Answer (score 5):

Here is my two cents:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=--(TEXTBEFORE(A1:A7," hour",,,,0)&TEXT(TEXTAFTER(" "&TEXTBEFORE(A1:A7," min",,,,0)," ",-1),"\:00"))
```

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
=LET(
    rng,TEXTSPLIT(A2," "),
    REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(rng)/2,,1,2),LAMBDA(a,b,a+INDEX(rng,b)/IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("hour",INDEX(rng,,b+1))),24,24*60))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is the alternative approach:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=MAP(A2:A5,LAMBDA(x,SUM(IFERROR(
     MID(0&x,SEARCH({"h","m"},0&x)-3,3),{0,0})
     *{"1:0","0:1"})))
```

---

Looks like you are using `Structured Reference` there the `Spill` will not work, hence you need to fill down formula use as shown below:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=MAP([@[Travel Time]],LAMBDA(x,SUM(IFERROR(
     MID(0&x,SEARCH({"h","m"},0&x)-3,3),{0,0})
     *{"1:0","0:1"})))
```

---